# How to show the some pixels of the next slide and or previous slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a very simple carousel slider, that you can check out here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjgvPj

Now I want to see some pixels of the next list item if the first slide is active, or if the second list item is active, I want to see some of the pixels from the previous one.

So this would look something like this, if your on the first slide:

[image: the red bar on the right represent some of the pixels of the next slide]

*The red bar on the right represent some of the pixels of the next slide*

And if you are somewhere in the middle of the slides, you will see left and right the next and previous slide:

[image]

*The two red bars on each side represents the previous and next slide*

My basic setup is: 
HTML:

```
<div class="inner">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <div>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x420">
            <div><span>Spring Mountains</span></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="">
          <div>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x420">
            <div><span>I Took this Yosemite</span></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a href="">
          <div>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x420">
            <div><span>I Took El Capitan</span></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <div>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x420">
            <div><span>Fourth</span></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
```

How do I achieve this?
I look out for your answer.
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
This time with colorful photos!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjgvPj

Comment: define `show some pixels`. Have you looked at horizontal accordions?

Comment: @charlietfl I have update my question.

Comment: different ways to do it ... hard to test on that demo when image colors are all the same

Comment: I make a try,  like charlietfl say the color of image doesn't help. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoZZRj (I add border to see what element overlap the other) (left: blue, right: green)

Comment: @hexaheart Here a new demo with colorful pictures: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjgvPj

Comment: @charlietfl See above comment ;)

Comment: simple to get a start..make inner 200px wider and set carousel ul padding left 100. Not perfect but gets you going. Hopefully you are familiar with doing live css edits in browser dev tools.

Comment: @charlietfl Do you also have the perfect one then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoZZGQ

I add a class for the selected `li`, to change the `z-index` property and define who overlap the other.

javascirpt :

```
  var current = $('#carousel ul li').get(index);
  current.classList.add('active');
  if(lastOne)
    lastOne.classList.remove('active');
  lastOne = current;
```

css:

```
#carousel ul li{
  z-index: 1;
}
#carousel ul li.active{
  z-index: 0;
}
```

add negative margin to get the overlap:

```
#carousel ul li{
  margin-right: -50px
}
```

And update the offset :
 `$('#carousel ul').animate({'margin-left': '-' + index*950});`

Comment: And is there a way to do this with some space between it, instead of the overlapped images?

Comment: Almost. So there is also space between the images.. Like the example above (the image one)